# Efficiency of a recursive implementation of the Sieve of Erasthotenes in Python

Tags: python, recursion, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I implemented the Sieve of Erasthotenes recursively using `filter` and I was wondering how efficient this implementation is and wether a non-recursive implementation or something without `filter` would be better. If someone wants to get into micro-optimization etc. - that would be fun too I suppose :)

This is my code:

```py
def sieve (iterable, container):
    if len(iterable) != 1:
        container.append(iterable [0])
        iterable = [item for item in iterable if item % iterable [0] != 0]
        print("Filter call:", iterable, container, '\n')
        return sieve(iterable, container)
    else: 
        container.append(iterable[0])
        print("Return container:", container)
        return container
```

An example I/O (with the print-Statements) would be:

```py
#Input
lst = list(range(2, 20))
primes = []

print(sieve(lst, primes)

#Output
Filter call: [3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19] [2] 

Filter call: [5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19] [2, 3] 

Filter call: [7, 11, 13, 17, 19] [2, 3, 5] 

Filter call: [11, 13, 17, 19] [2, 3, 5, 7] 

Filter call: [13, 17, 19] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11] 

Filter call: [17, 19] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13] 

Filter call: [19] [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17] 

Return container: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]

#Return
Out: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Algorithm

This is not quite the Sieve of Eratosthenes. The true sieve touches only the multiples of each prime, so it has complexity \$n \log \log n\$. Filtering copies the whole list repeatedly, which is equivalent to a different algorithm, *trial division*, with different complexity (probably \$n^2 / (\log n)^2\$). That's a dramatic difference, which led Melissa O'Neill to write a [slightly famous academic rant](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) about this.

But that's not a problem for an educational program. The rest of this review is about your implementation.

Recursing on each prime has depth \$\pi(n) \approx n / \log n\$, which will overflow the stack for any large \$n\$. Can you do it iteratively instead?

## Names

`iterable` is a misleading name: the function uses `len(iterable)`, but iterables don't necessarily support `len`. So it doesn't work on all iterables.

`iterable` is also an uninformative name: it doesn't say what the argument *means*. It isn't just any iterable, it's a list of candidate primes, so it could be called `candidates`.

Similarly, `container` isn't just any container, it's a list of primes, so it should be called `primes`. Also, `sieve` modifies it, which is unusual enough that it requires a comment, and it could even appear in the name: it could be called `output_primes`.

## Interface

Modifying an argument is confusing and error-prone. Why not build a list and return it?

Why does the caller need to provide a list of candidates? Wouldn't it be simpler to just pass `n` and have `sieve` take care of building the candidates?

If the recursive function needs a different interface from the caller, you can use one function to do the recursion, and wrap it with another that presents a clean interface to the caller.

## Innards

Repetition: `container.append(iterable[0])` appears in both branches of the `if`. It could be moved before the `if`.

The program checks `len(iterable) != 1`, so what happens if `len(iterable) == 0`? Oops: it tries to use `iterable[0]` and crashes. It's generally safest to check for 0, not 1. This would also get rid of the repetition.

## Optimization

Improving the algorithm will help a lot more than micro-optimizing. If you switch to the true Sieve of Eratosthenes and it still isn't fast enough, there are algorithmic improvements like the [Sieve of Sundaram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram).

Before optimizing, measure performance! Optimization is hard and it's easy to get it wrong, so let measurements guide you.

## Other

This function should have a docstring saying what it does: `"Prime number sieve: Given a list of candidates, append the primes to output_primes."`

Your question says the program uses `filter`, but it actually uses a list comprehension to do the same thing. This is not a problem with the program, just slightly confusing.